# Joomla mac os x server, could not init jk log lock in child

Tags: macos, apache, webserver

I had an mac os x server, and would install joomla. I created an subdomain an put all joomla files in it, but it doesn't, I get the follwoing error. What I have to do?

No such file or directory mod_jk could not init jk log lock in child